# Matching messages to handlers by type

Tags: haskell, event-handling, pattern-matching, messaging

I have a large *open* set of message types and a list of handlers `Message -> IO ()`, each expecting a certain type of message and ignoring all others.

I need a function `anymessage -> [Message -> IO ()] -> IO ()`. I could make this work with `type Message = Dynamic` or even `type Message = String` (and `show`/`read`).

Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: What's `anymessage`? It's not a legal type name

Comment: @Benesh, I'm open to suggestions :). Most likely there should be a `class AnyMessage` and then the function is `(AnyMessage m) => m -> [Message -> IO ()] -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the usual extensible exceptions/message handler. See:

- /[An Extensible Dynamically-Typed Hierarchy of Exceptions](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf)/, Simon Marlow, 2006.

See e.g. [XMonad's Message class](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Core.html#Message):

```
--
-- User-extensible messages must be a member of this class.
--
class Typeable a => Message a

-- |
-- A wrapped value of some type in the 'Message' class.
--
data SomeMessage = forall a. Message a => SomeMessage a

-- |
-- And now, unwrap a given, unknown 'Message' type, performing a (dynamic)
-- type check on the result.
--
fromMessage :: Message m => SomeMessage -> Maybe m
fromMessage (SomeMessage m) = cast m

-- X Events are valid Messages.
instance Message Event
```

etc etc.

Comment: So, that's essentially `Dynamic`. I don't suppose there would be an extension to hide those casts with something like a regular pattern matching?

Comment: It's dynamic to wrap the runtime value, but only static instances are supported. The cast is 'hidden' via the smart constructor that processes the message. You may find some other solution in open, extensible data types, but this at least is well supported and widely used.